# How do I use the 7z sdk to extract rar/zip files (C++)?

Tags: c++, 7zip

I'm trying to write a small, cross-platform comic book reader (Qt / C++). I don't care what's already out there, I know there are some.

My problem is that I need to read the comic book formats, which are renamed rar and zip files.

The documentation is very... nonexistent? There's no "hello archive" document anywho.
How can I set this up?

If It makes it easier to assume I'm on any particular OS, do so. I'm switching between Kubuntu, OSX, and Win7 constantly for dev work.

Comment: http://quazip.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

I've been working on a simple C++ wrapper for the 7zip SDK, which you can find [here](https://bitbucket.org/cmcnab/sevenzip/overview).  It currently only supports Windows and the specific needs I had, but I'd be happy to make some alterations and/or accept contributions.  It can extract 7zip and Zip files in a few lines of code, using the 7z.dll.  RAR shouldn't be difficult to add since the DLL supports it.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this:
 `fatal error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20100826' and 'P2' version '20070207` error on SevenZip++?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that error, but googling around a bit it sounds like it may be an issue with your Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 3):

7z should actually come with both source for a commandline variant and a GUI variant, you could dig into to those and see how they do the compression, else you could use [unRar](http://www.win-rar.com/rarextras.html) and see if that has any examples(unfortunatly I can't check due to the download being blocked where I am).

---

Poking around the LMZA SDK a bit I came across this:

> ANSI-C LZMA Decoder
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Please note that interfaces for ANSI-C
>   code were changed in LZMA SDK 4.58. If
>   you want to use old interfaces you can
>   download previous version of LZMA SDK
>   from sourceforge.net site.
>
> To use ANSI-C LZMA Decoder you need
>   the following files: 
>   1) LzmaDec.h + LzmaDec.c + Types.h
>
> LzmaUtil/LzmaUtil.c is example
>   application that uses these files.